# jackson xml serialize list of strings to concatenated string

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

In my class there is a list of strings. Now I need to serialize this list into a single concatenated string separated by line breaks.

```
public class Address{

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ADDRESS_FIELD")
    @JacksonXmlCData
    private List<String> addressLines;

    // Irrelevant parts omitted

}
```

Suppose the list contains three elements: Row 1, Row 2, and Row 3. How do I get the following output?

```
<ADDRESS_FIELD>
<![CDATA[
Row1
Row2
Row3
]]>
</ADDRESS_FIELD>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer` serialiser and wrap content in required form manually into `CDATA`:

```
class JoinListToStringJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<?>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<?> list, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        final String delimiter = System.lineSeparator();

        String value = list.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));

        gen.writeRawValue(delimiter + "<![CDATA[" + delimiter + value + delimiter + "]]>");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ADDRESS_FIELD")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
@JsonSerialize(using = JoinListToStringJsonSerializer.class)
private List<String> addressLines;
```